# To delete the edited input and update the it in the current input

Tags: reactjs, delete-file

Sorry if I have my question not explained properlY, Im pretty noob at react and I need help from you guys, Thank you.
To explain it elaborately, my editing state gets updated perfectly but the problem is when I try to delete it, it is deleting the last added value. I know I have to update the state on click of the delete button but I dont know how.. Little help would be helpful. This is the whole code. Please let me know where did I went wrong and give a solution for that.
***app.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from './input_bar';
import TaskList from './tasklist';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            inputValue:"",
            todos: [
                {value: 'Clean the room', done: false},
                {value: 'Wake up early', done:true}
            ],
            check:true,
            isHidden: true
        }
        this.onInputChange=this.onInputChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onCheckClick=this.onCheckClick.bind(this);
        this.onDeleteClick=this.onDeleteClick.bind(this);
        this.onClearCompleted=this.onClearCompleted.bind(this);
        this.onCheckUncheckAll=this.onCheckUncheckAll.bind(this);
        this.noOfItems=this.noOfItems.bind(this);
    }

    onInputChange(event){
        this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value});
    }

    onSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const newTodo ={
            value:this.state.inputValue,
            done:false
        };
        const todos = this.state.todos;
        todos.push(newTodo);
        this.setState({todos, inputValue:''})
    }

    onCheckClick(index){
        const todos= this.state.todos;
        todos[index].done= !todos[index].done;
        this.noOfItems();
        this.setState({todos})
    }

    onDeleteClick(index){
        const todos=this.state.todos;
        todos.splice(index,1);
        this.setState({todos});
    }

    onClearCompleted(){
        const todos=this.state.todos;

        for( let i = 0 ; i < todos.length; i++){
            if ( todos[i].done === true) {
                todos.splice(i, 1);
                i=i-1;
            }
        }
        this.setState({todos});
    }

    onCheckUncheckAll(){
        const todos= this.state.todos;
        for( let i = 0 ; i < todos.length; i++){
            todos[i].done= this.state.check;
            this.setState({check: !this.state.check});
        }
        this.setState({todos});
    }

    noOfItems(){
        const todos=this.state.todos;
        let itemsLeft = todos.length;
        for( let i = 0 ; i < todos.length; i++) {
            if (todos[i].done === true) {
                itemsLeft = itemsLeft - 1;
            }
        }
        return(itemsLeft);
    }

    render() {
     return (
       <div>

          <Input
              onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
              inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
              onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
              onCheckUncheckAll={this.onCheckUncheckAll}
          />

          <TaskList
              onCheckClick={this.onCheckClick}
              onDeleteClick={this.onDeleteClick}
              onClearCompleted={this.onClearCompleted}
              noOfItems={this.noOfItems}
              todos={this.state.todos}
          />

       </div>
     );
    }
}
```

***input_bar.js***

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Input extends React.Component{


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="Form">
                <button onClick={this.props.onCheckUncheckAll} className="CheckUncheck">
                    <i className="fa fa-angle-down"/>
                </button>
                <form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                    <input
                        value={this.props.inputValue}
                        onChange={this.props.onInputChange}
                        className="toggle-all"
                        placeholder="What needs to be done?"
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

***tasklist.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import TaskListItem from './tasklistitems';

export default class TaskList extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="List">
                {this.props.todos.map((todo, index) => {
                    return(
                        <TaskListItem
                            key={index}
                            index={index}
                            todo={todo}
                            onCheckClick={this.props.onCheckClick}
                            onDeleteClick={this.props.onDeleteClick}
                            noOfItems={this.props.noOfItems}
                        />
                    );
                })}
                <span>  {this.props.noOfItems()} items left </span>
                <a onClick={this.props.onClearCompleted} className="clearCompleted">Clear Completed</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**tasklistitems.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Ionicon from 'react-ionicons'

export default class TaskListItem extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            edit: false,
            currentValue: this.props.todo.value
        }

    }

    tick(){
        return(
                <Ionicon icon="ios-radio-button-off" fontSize="25px" color="#EDEDED"/>
        )
    }

    untick(){
        return(
                <Ionicon icon="ios-checkmark-circle-outline" fontSize="25px" color="#57C1AF"/>
        )
    }

    onEdit(event){
        this.setState({edit: true, currentValue: this.state.currentValue});
    }

    onEditDone(event){
        if(event.keyCode===13){
            //console.log(this.state.currentValue);
            this.setState({edit:false});
            this.props.todo.value= this.state.currentValue;
        }
    }

    onEditChange(event) {
        let _currentValue = event.target.value;
        //console.log("currentvalue",this.state.currentValue);
        this.setState({currentValue: _currentValue});
    }

    // onDeleteChange(){
    //
    //     // ----------------- What should I put here ---------------//
    //
    //
    // }

    render(){
        //console.log(this.state.currentValue);
        const viewStyle={};
        const editStyle={};

        if(this.state.edit){
            viewStyle.display= 'none';
        }else{
            editStyle.display='none';
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <div style={viewStyle}>
                    <div className="Task row" >
                        <div className="col-md-2">
                            <button onClick={()=>this.props.onCheckClick(this.props.index)}>
                                {this.props.todo.done ? this.untick():this.tick() }
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <span >
                            <div className="col-md-9" onDoubleClick={this.onEdit.bind(this)}>
                                <span style={{color:this.props.todo.done ?'#e6e6e6' : '#4d4d4d',
                                    textDecoration: this.props.todo.done ? '#e6e6e6 line-through' : 'none',
                                    transition: 'text-decoration 0.5s, color 0.5s'
                                }}
                                >
                                    {this.state.currentValue}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <div className="col-md-1">
                            <button onClick={()=>this.props.onDeleteClick(this.props.index)} onMouseDown={onDeleteChange.bind(this)} className="destroy">
                                x
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="text"
                       onChange={this.onEditChange.bind(this)}
                       onKeyDown={this.onEditDone.bind(this)}
                       style={editStyle}
                       value={this.state.currentValue}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**
You don't need to manage  `currentValue` on `<TaskListItem/>`'s state. You should use `this.props.todo.value` to render it instead. Here is the [fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/wyn72yok35)

**in detail:**
This bug is caused due to the fact that on the `<TaskListItem />` component, you are using the `todo.value` prop in order to set the Item's current value on the component's constructor (`currentValue: this.props.todo.value`) and using this state attribute in order to render this value (`{this.state.currentValue}`).

Since this value is dynamically passed as a prop by parent components when this value changes (for example - when an item is deleted) - it causes the value not to change when a new value is passed to the component via props since it gets it from its internal state (which doesn't update every time a the props' values change).

In other words. You need to change your **source of truth** for this value from the state to the props. Your **single source of truth** for the `todos` data (their `value` and `done` values) should be the parent App component.

I order to fix this issue you need to use the value from the props (`{this.props.todo.value}`) in the render method of `<TaskListItem />` instead of the value from the state (`{this.state.currentValue}`
)

Here is a [fixed example version of your app](https://codesandbox.io/s/wyn72yok35)

(I commeneted out the bits which were causing the bug)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: after you double click the list.. it should edit the current line and update it..

Comment: so you should find a way to make this update on the parent App state. And pass this method via props to the <TaskListItem />.  Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah a little bit.. kinda working on that.. just figuring out how to do that.. thanks for the help.. ;)

Comment: `onEditChange` should be a method on the App component which changes the vlaue of the todo item base on it's index

Comment: Got it dude.. thanks for the help.. just take the link from the above post dude.. so that I can give a verified answer to this.. it was very helpful

Comment: here, I've updated the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wyn72yok35) to make it work: